# Don't know how to fix this file doesn't exist error

Tags: python, python-2.7

The file combo.txt exists but when I run the program it gives an error. I tried to run it multiple times but it gives the same error, I don't know what else to do.

```
def failed(email, password):
    pass
def passed(email, password):
    pass
def checker(email, password):
    pass
combos_name = input("please enter combos name: ")
combos = open(combos_name, "r").readLines()
arrange = [lines.replace("\n", "") for lines in combos]
for lines in arrange:
    lines.split(":")
    print(lines)
```

Error:

```
C:\Checker\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Checker/checker.py
please enter combos name: combo.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Checker/checker.py", line 15, in <module>
    combos = open(combos_name, "r").readLines()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'combo.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it in your project directory? If not, assign a full path like `C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Path\\To\\combos.txt`

Comment: Could use a `filedialog` and avoid typing it in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method of calling a filedialog for selecting the file vs typing it in:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, filedialog

def failed(email, password):
    pass
def passed(email, password):
    pass
def checker(email, password):
    pass
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

#combos_name = input("please enter combos name: ")

combos_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "./", title = "Select file")

combos = open(combos_name, "r").readlines()
arrange = [lines.replace("\n", "") for lines in combos]
for lines in arrange:
    lines.split(":")
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your file does not exist, or does not exist in the current directory.
You can make sure that your file `code.txt` is in the same directory with a code you are executing.

To fix this problem you can try to pass the abolute path to `code.txt` file.

Also, you can use the `os` module to check if file exists or to check your current directory.

```
import os
print(os.path.exists('code.txt'))  # check if code.txt exists
print(os.getcwd())  # check current directory
print(os.listdir())  # list all files in current directory
```